# My Login script automatically logs out

Tags: php, session

I made myself a login script, but now when I sign in, It goes to the home page and when i click on a other page it signs me out. When i sign back in. It does work.

This is my login script:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
if($sQuery = $db->query("SELECT salt, id FROM users WHERE email='".$db- >real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'")){
    $sFetch = $sQuery->fetch_assoc();
    if($lQuery = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND password='".crypt($_POST['password'], $sFetch['salt'])."'")){
        if($lQuery->num_rows > 0){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $sFetch['id'];
            header('Location: home'); 
            exit();
        }else{
            $errorlogin = "Je email of wachtwoord klopt niet.";
        }    
    }else{
        $errorlogin = "Er is iets misgegaan. Foutmelding: ".$db->error;
    }
}else{
    $errorlogin = "Er is iets misgegaan. Foutmelding: ".$db->error;
}
}
```

And this is my index:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("includes/class.database.php");


if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    include("ingelogd.php"); //When signed in
}else{
    include("inloggen.php"); //when not signed in
}
?>
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: did you started session on login page ?

Comment: Have you check $_SESSION['id'] variable in index page? isset or not?

Comment: Kindly post the code of "other page" too, to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also check if the session variable is available for the script..use empty() test instead of isset

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['id'])){
    include("ingelogd.php"); //When signed in
}else{
    include("inloggen.php"); //when not signed in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the space intentional in the first `.$db- >real_escape_string` ?